# Visual Studio and Remote IIS Site: Unable to access remote IIS after working in local-machine IIS

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-2012

My company has an older, Sharepoint-based website hosted on our development environment (Windows Server 2008), managed by IIS 7. Most of the devs in my environment work on these sites by logging into the environment via Remote Desktop, then using the remote Visual Studio 2012 installation.

I don't love using a remote installation of VS for development work, so for the past several weeks, I've been using the following workaround:

- I added the drives of our remote environment as network locations on my local machine.
- From there, I gave my local Visual Studio 2015 installation the paths as `\\{remote_machine_name}\c$\inetpub...` etc.

Visual Studio gave me no complaints, and everything went quite smoothly. Today, I had to work with an IIS installation on my local machine. Our company is preparing to switch from Sharepoint to DNN, so I'm doing some preliminary porting and testing on a local installation of DNN using IIS 10. That's when the error started up.

During the configuration process of DNN, I had to change a few lines in the config file at `%systemroot%\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.xml`. This was because DNN was giving me 500.19 errors after installation. IIS's support said this was likely related to locking of permission regions in this file, and directed me to change the behavior of any locks that gave errors from "Deny" to "Allow".

I can still work via Remote Desktop, but it would be nice to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing IIS 10 using the downloadable installer. I realized I would have to do this when Visual Studio 2015 would not allow me to create any web projects.